# How to chain methods dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, methods, populate

I'm looking to populate various paths of a document with Mongoose but I can't find a way to dynamically chain the various populate methods. It's important to retrieve all these fields in one go for performance. Here is the code:

```
let fields = [path1, path2, ...]

let result = document.findById(id).populate(path1).populate(path2).populate(...)
```

Does any of you know of such sorcery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for:

```js
let query = document.findById(id)

for (const field of fields) {
  query = query.populate(field)
}

const result = await query
```

if you want to go with ES6 [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const result = await fields.reduce((query, field) => query.populate(field), document.findById(id))
```

**Edit**:

From mongoose v3.6 you can use also `.populate(fields.join(' '))`

Comment: Hmm wouldn't query just hold the value of the last query.populate(field) with only one field populated ?

Comment: Nope, it's equivalent to `.populate().populate()` etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
const result = fields.reduce((r, path) => r.populate(path), document.findById(id));
```

Or somewhat more verbosely:

```
let result = document.findById(id);
for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    result = result.populate(fields[i]);
}
```